# How to create a custom (ElevatedButton) class constructor with different parameters than its parent class constructor?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a custom button class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PlayButton extends ElevatedButton {
  PlayButton(
      {required this.buttonText,
      required this.buttonColor,
      required this.onPress});

  final void Function()? onPress;
  final String buttonText;
  final Color buttonColor;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: onPress,
      child: Text(
        buttonText,
        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Verdana'),
      ),
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        onPrimary: Colors.white,
        primary: buttonColor,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
        ),
        minimumSize: Size(100, 100),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I get an error message saying `The superclass 'ElevatedButton' doesn't have a zero argument constructor.`

`Try declaring a zero argument constructor in 'ElevatedButton', or explicitly invoking a different constructor in 'ElevatedButton'.`

I can write the constructor as something like:

```
PlayButton(
      {required this.buttonText,
      required this.buttonColor,
      required this.onPress})
      : super(child: Text('a'), onPressed: null);
```

and remove the error message, but all that's displayed is the default superclass button (with 'a' text). So how can I have a constructor inherit from a parent class while having different parameters than the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you don't need to inherit `ElevatedButton` at all. Flutter favors composition over inheritance anyway.

Just remove `extends ElevatedButton` and use `extends StatelessWidget` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Pass on the properties of the child class to the parent class as follows:

```
PlayButton(
      {required this.buttonText,
      required this.buttonColor,
      required this.onPress})
      : super(child: Text(this.buttonText), onPressed: this.onPress);
```

Hopefully, this should fix the issue.